# Render ANSI colour with Qt4?

Tags: pyqt4, qt4, ansi-c

I would like to render ANSI colour with Qt4 in a QLabel or QTextEdit or anything else that would do.

Right now the `QLabel(""\033[94m HELLO \033[0m"")` renders the string as is.

How can I render ANSI colour or what is a good alternative in Qt4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to parse the string. A QLabel is either going to display plain text or html. That means you will need to transform it into html spans most likely.

Comment: OK, Html it is then: `QtGui.QLabel('<font style="background-color: blue">HELLO</font>')`. And it's easier too, the ANSI code is so confusing.